# Find the min and max dates between multiple sets of dates

Tags: sql-server, date-range

Given the following set of data, I'm trying to determine how I can select the start and end dates of the combined date ranges, when they intersect with each other.

For instance, for PartNum 115678, I would want my final result set to display the date ranges `2012/01/01 - 2012/01/19` (rows 1, 2 and 4 combined since the date ranges intersect) and `2012/02/01 - 2012/03/28` (row 3 since this ones does not intersect with the range found previously).

For PartNum 213275, I would want to select the only row for that part, `2012/12/01 - 2013/01/01`.

[image: example-data]

Edit:
I'm currently playing around with the following SQL statement, but it's not giving me exactly what I need.

```
with DistinctRanges as (
    select distinct
        ha1.PartNum "PartNum",
        ha1.StartDt "StartDt",
        ha2.EndDt "EndDt"
    from dbo.HoldsAll ha1
    inner join dbo.HoldsAll ha2 
        on ha1.PartNum = ha2.PartNum
    where 
        ha1.StartDt <= ha2.EndDt 
        and ha2.StartDt <= ha1.EndDt
)
select 
    PartNum, 
    StartDt, 
    EndDt
from DistinctRanges
```

Here are the results of the query shown in the edit:

[image: results from inline query]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're better off having a persisted Calendar table, but if you don't, the CTE below will create it ad-hoc.  The `TOP(36000)` part is enough to give you 10 years worth of dates from the pivot (`'20100101'`) on the same line.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5d5b0/1)

**MS SQL Server 2008 Schema Setup**:

```
create table data (
    partnum int,
    startdt datetime,
    enddt datetime,
    age int
);
insert data select 
12345, '20120101', '20120116', 15 union all select
12345, '20120115', '20120116', 1 union all select
12345, '20120201', '20120328', 56 union all select
12345, '20120113', '20120119', 6 union all select
88872, '20120201', '20130113', 43;
```

**Query 1**:

```
with Calendar(thedate) as (
    select TOP(36600) dateadd(d,row_number() over (order by 1/0),'20100101')
      from sys.columns a
cross join sys.columns b
cross join sys.columns c
), tmp as (
   select partnum, thedate,
          grouper = datediff(d, dense_rank() over (partition by partnum order by thedate), thedate)
     from Calendar c
     join data d on d.startdt <= c.thedate and c.thedate <= d.enddt
)
select partnum, min(thedate) startdt, max(thedate) enddt
  from tmp
 group by partnum, grouper
 order by partnum, startdt
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5d5b0/1/0)**:

```
| PARTNUM |                         STARTDT |                          ENDDT |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   12345 |  January, 01 2012 00:00:00+0000 | January, 19 2012 00:00:00+0000 |
|   12345 | February, 01 2012 00:00:00+0000 |   March, 28 2012 00:00:00+0000 |
|   88872 | February, 01 2012 00:00:00+0000 | January, 13 2013 00:00:00+0000 |
```

Comment: @RichardTheKiwi: I just came across your minesweeper code written in T-SQL which just blew my mind now and the very next moment i saw your ans to this SO question which is simply amazing .

Comment: @Praveen Thanks for the compliment :)

Comment: RichardTheKiwi, thanks for your code. When i use it is starts @ 2 jan 2010, so maybe you can start @ 20091231 instead of 20100101, so you start @ 1 jan 2010 :)

Comment: Great answer!, I was looking into the `cross join` statements, but understand they are just to create an iterator. In that case, only one (i.e. only the first `cross join` b) is required as -in my case- that leads to 3500 x 3500 rows = 12,250,000 rows